# Form submit - override default submit action and prompt to confirm

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a basic HTML form into which I wish to place a form with two buttons - update, and delete.

My form specifies the default action as /updateanalaysts, whilst I would like the delete buttons action to be /deleteanalyst. to make life a little more complicated I'm trying to display a confirmation prompt when Delete is clicked.

What seems to be happening in my code currently is that /updateanalysts is always being invoked, even when delete is clicked. This might be because I'm using preventDefault so that when cancel on the prompt is clicked the form is not submitted?

Any advice on how to rectify this issue would be very welcome.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>{{{payload.style}}}</style>
  </head>

<div>
  <form method="post" action="/{{url}}" ajax="true">
    <label for="fname">ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="fbanNo" name="ID" value="{{{payload.0.ID}}}" required>
    
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" value="{{{payload.0.First_Name}}}" required>

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" value="{{{payload.0.Last_Name}}}" required>
  
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" action="/deleteanalyst" id="deletebutton">
  </form>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="result"></span>
</div>


<script>
var delbutton = document.getElementById("deletebutton")
delbutton.addEventListener("click", function (event) { 
    if (!confirm('Confirm you wish to delete this entry?')) { event.preventDefault(); } 
}, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That said, you have an invalid `ajax="true"` attribute on the form so I expect you have some other JavaScript that you removed from your test case before including it here which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Tigger — I don't see how that relates to the question at all.

Comment: *Danger* — You are using an old, unsupported version of jQuery with known security issues: https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery@2.1.0

Comment: @Quentin The issue is that when I click OK the wrong form action is triggered.

Comment: @anakaine — Oh. That's a typo. Use a validator. The attribute name is `formaction` not `action`.

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried ```<input type="submit" value="Delete" formaction="/deleteanalyst" id="deletebutton">``` but am still seeing the same result. Is that what you meant?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-formaction

Comment: It works when I use it, but that brings us back to `ajax="true"`

Comment: Righto. That's a pain. There's some things here I cannot easily change, and that's one of the big ones due to some back end linkages. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use event.preventDefault() method on the delete button
and add a input hiden for operation info

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.onreset        =_=>myForm.operation.value = 'Update'  //default value
myForm.Update.onclick =_=>myForm.operation.value = 'Update'
myForm.Delete.onclick =_=>myForm.operation.value = 'Delete'

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  if (myForm.operation.value==='Delete'
  && !confirm(`please confirm delete of ${myForm.firstname.value}`)
   ){
    e.preventDefault() // disable submit
    }

  // show entries  
  e.preventDefault() // just for testing any cases
  console.log('data:', Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries()))
  setTimeout(console.clear, 5000)
  }
```

```css
label, button {
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : left;
  margin  : .3em;
  }

.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:50% !important; width:50%; }
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<form name="my-form" method="post" action="/xxx" ajax="true">

  <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="Update">
  
  <label>
    ID
    <input type="text" name="ID" value=" 0.ID " required>
  </label>
  <label>
    First Name
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" First_Nam " required>
  </label>
  <label>
    Last Name
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" Last_Name " required>
  </label>

  <button type="submit" name="Update">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" name="Delete">Delete</button>
  <button type="reset" >Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Someone closed this question with a private comment claiming it was caused by a typo. It was not a typo and your answer was very helpful.